# Pentaho DI missing or skipping rows

Tags: pentaho, data-integration

I have problem with pentaho data integration tool. I made some ETL to insert rows to fact table, but the problem is that not all rows are inserted to fact table. I ran pentaho several times and every time it gives me different results. Sometimes there are 57 rows skipping and sometimes 55. I tried to change some options in Pentaho Spoon like Commit Size in Table output, or Nr of rows in rowset in Transformation properties, but all the times with different results.

**Main job** which runs all transformations:
[image]

**Transformation** which causes this problem:
[image]

All transformations that are running:
[image]

Comment: I had similar problems in a transformation, so it's only a vague idea: Are there two hops leaving one step which are not copying the data?

Comment: @Seb I edit my question. There are many transformations in run_facts_for_each_row job but there are running one after another.

Comment: As I found out this was a problem of mysql-server. I had installed version 5.6.16.0 and when I installed 5.6.21.1 it fixed problem with missing rows. I don't know what was wrong with older version, since I have not changed anything

Comment: I'm having the same issue on MySQL 5.7